# After applying custom theme Action bar dosen't show up

Tags: android, styles, android-actionbar, themes

I have an application using action bar

styles.xml

```
    <resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.

    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.

        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

    <color name="custom_theme_color">#ffa900</color>

    <style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/custom_theme_color</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/custom_theme_color</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.actionbar"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/CustomTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.actionbar.ActionBarActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My Question is that initially by default  it was using Theme.Light and action bar is displayed but when I have customized a theme using parent as Theme.Light it dosen't work but if I use parent as Theme.Holo then it works for custom theme. Anyone any Idea.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have done. It is working perfectly for me. In Res->value->style

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
<style name="CustomTheme"
       parent="@style/Theme.Light">       

       <item android:name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

</style>
<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style android:name="MyActionBar"
       parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
              <item android:name="background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item> 
</style>
</resources>
```

Then in drawable folder(create one if you don't have it),create a new xml actionbar_background and paste the below code in it.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <bitmap android:tileMode="repeat" 
    android:src="@drawable/ab_texture_tile_example" 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>
```

Then you place your custom colour in the other drawable folders. Here ab_texture_title_example is my background colour used.

Comment: Use the below link to create a custom background colour.
http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/